Automatically center the floats with the standalone class?
This is a follow-up of a question of mine (Why \AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\centering} doesn't center the figures?) where @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz gave me the nice trick \AddToHook{cmd/@floatboxreset/after}{\centering} which works nicely for automatically center floats with usual classes:
\documentclass{article}
\AddToHook{cmd/@floatboxreset/after}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Unfortunately, this trick fails with the standalone class:
\documentclass[varwidth=15cm]{standalone}
\AddToHook{cmd/@floatboxreset/after}{\centering}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Is there a way to automatically center floats with the standalone class (used with its varwidth option)?

\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\AddToHook{cmd/item/before}{\centering}}.

Play with \ShowCommand\figure, you'll notice that standalone, despite loading article the floats are defined to not float. Thus does not use the same internals. As Ulrike writes, the non floats in standalone are trivlists.

@UlrikeFischer That does the trick, thanks! Would you convert your comment into an answer?

@daleif The output of \ShowCommand\figure is the same with the standalone and the article classes.

Sorry, meant \ShowCommand\@float

In the standalone class floats are not floats but simple trivlists. So try with
\AddToHook{env/figure/begin}{\AddToHook{cmd/item/before}{\centering}}.


Unfortunately, this has the side effect to center all the lists in the document.

... at least all the lists that follow the first figure environment.

@DenisBitouzé well I don't think that make any sense to put lots of lists in a standalone document, but you naturally can remove the hook code after the figure again.

Meanwhile, I indeed found the same solution: \AddToHook{env/figure/end}{\RemoveFromHook{cmd/item/before}}. The reason for using the standalone class is to create single-page documents (which can contain lists :)
